# automatic call distribution or call forwarding in asterisk

Tags: asterisk

Can we do automatic call distribution in asterisk(in built conf or something)?
Means as per consideration of
there is x,y,z are 3 call receivers & a,b,c are call dialer & all dialer dont know about x,y,z they always consider they are calling x only.
Now if x busy with a,& same time b try to call to x then its call should divert to y or z(any one who free).
So for achieve this should i use only call divert method which example in

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+call+forwarding

Or should i go for as http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Automatic+Call+Distributor

But for automatic call distribution or call forwarding can i use asterisk old version which currently i am using 1.6.2.6 or i have to upgrade it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use queue application or ringgroup or create your own diaplan as you wish.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+call+forwarding

Also any asterisk-related book will help, for example

http://cdn.oreilly.com/books/9780596510480.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If standard Asterisk ACD tools such as:

http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449332426/asterisk-ACD.html

http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/ACD_id288932.html

... then another alternative is to use an AGI to get the effect you are looking for.  Instead of queuing the call via Asterisk, use call parking or dynamic meetme and have your AGI "do the right thing" to get the call to the agent.